# node.js, express: send email with 'nodemailer' and 'nodemailer-handlebars' giving TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send email through an HTML template that resides in the same path under a folder named 'view'. The HTML template name is 'index.handlebars'. But it is giving some weird error of path, though I think the path is absolutely proper.
Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
at Object.resolve (path.js:161:7)
at ExpressHandlebars._resolveLayoutPath (E:\NODE JS EXAMPLES\node-practice-one\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:342:17)
at ExpressHandlebars. (E:\NODE JS EXAMPLES\node-practice-one\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:223:35)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-handlebars');
const log = console.log;

// Step 1
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL || 'abcd@gmail.com', // TODO: your gmail    account
   pass: process.env.PASSWORD || 'abcd' // TODO: your gmail password
  }
});

router.post('/send_mail', (req, res, next) => {
  // Step 2
 transporter.use(
    'compile',
    hbs({
     viewEngine: 'express-handlebars',
     viewPath: './views/'
   })
 );

  // Step 3
  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxx@gmail.com', // TODO: email sender
    to: 'yyy@gmail.com', // TODO: email receiver
    subject: 'Nodemailer - Test',
    text: 'Wooohooo it works!!',
    template: 'index',
    context: {
     name: 'test user'
    } // send extra values to template
  };

  // Step 4
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
    console.log(err);

    if (err) {
      return log('Error occurs');
    }
    return log('Email sent!!!');
  });
});
```

Please suggest to me, what should I do to fix the error.

Comment: you should use (i think) `nodemailer-express-handlebars` `https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-express-handlebars` because the package you are using is deprecated. The github page points to `nodemailer-express-handlebars` instead.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty: I have tested with the 'nodemailer-express-handlebars' package also, but it is also giving the error.

Error: A partials dir must be a string or config object

Comment: I have fixed the above issue with the 'nodemailer-express-handlebars' package. Someone has posted the answer in this link and it works for me.
https://github.com/yads/nodemailer-express-handlebars/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

inside hbs options you did not mention layoutsDir which contains layout.hbs

layout.hbs holds the default HTML skeleton and this is the file which will be extended by all the other view files. By default files in “views” folder will use this basic skeleton and then render their specific content in this {{{body}}} part. this is the hook where other views will come in and render their content.

```
hbs({
defaultLayout: "layout",
extname: ".hbs",
layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts", 
partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials"})
```

then inside views folder create layouts folder and partials folder. create layout.hbs inside layouts directory.  inside this file insert a basic html skeleton and inside the body, place this

```
{{{body}}}
```